# Deploying ASP.net application developed using VS2008express edition on MServer 2008

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-ajax, windows-server-2008

I want to deploy a Website which i have created using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition onto a server having Microsoft Windows Server 2008.

I dont know anything about deployment. I want to know what are the things required on the Server in order to make the application work.

i had used ajax toolkit VS2008 Express Edition and mysql on my developer machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have full access to the server or are you using a hosting provider?

When you say Website, do you mean your project is a Website project or is it a Web Application project?

If it's a website project you should use the WebDeploy project add-in. In fact you'll need this since the Web Deploy project will merge all your pages into one dll. I'm not sure of the limitation of the Express Edition no you'll need to check.

[WebDeployment Project post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx)

[Deploying a WebSite project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9.aspx)

[Deploying a Web Application Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326356)